# How to get the model that initiates a saveAll call in the related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to get the Model that is trying to save data to a related model in a saveAll transaction. If forexample, User hasMany Goal, and I make a call;

```
$this->User->saveAll($data);
```

Can I get the Model User in the Goal Model class using some predefined attritbute, method or mechanism?

Thanks for your help in advance,
Roland.

Edit:
Assume a hypothetical situation where a user has pictures, with a Picture model and Posts( blogs) with a corresponding model. These both can be commented upon. So rather than creating a separate comment model for each of these models, I create one central Comment model. The association might look like this;

```
    //In the Picture model
    var $hasMany = array(
``    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'picture_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.objectType' => 'picture')
      )`
    );
```

The association for the Post model will be similar, the only difference being;

```
'conditions' => array('Comment.objectType' => 'post')
```

With this structure, if I were to query any of these Models, their corresponding comments will be retrieved from the DB table using the objectType field.

If I were to do something like;

```
$this->Picture->saveAll($data);
```

, or

```
$this->Post->saveAll($data);
```

with the $data array well structured and containing a Comments part to be saved, at some point in time during the saving transaction, data will be saved to the comments table through the Comment model.
What I want is to be able to know that it is the Picture model trying to save comment in the Comment model's beforeSave method, i.e;

```
//In the Comment mode
    beforeSave() {
      //Post model is trying to save a comment here
    }
```

Comment: To clarify - you want it to check what data other than User data it's trying to save - and depending on that data/model, do something/run a function.  Y/n?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Give an example of what you are trying to do. I think that is why your question was down voted. It's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

With CakePHP, if you associate your models using the hasMany, while you are in the controller you can access that model.

In UserModel

```php
var $hasMany = array('Goal');
```

In GoalModel

```php
function myCrazyFunc() {
    //crazy stuff happens here
}
```

In UsersController

```php
$this->Goal->myCrazyFunc();
//more stuff
$this->User->saveAll($data);
```